# How to change the ui.bootstrap.datepicker popup date selected programmatically?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a clear button that when pressed needs to reset the `input` value to the default date (today) *as well as* the button in the datepicker popup. The issue I'm having is the date watermark value in the `input` text control does successfully get set to the default date upon pressing the 'clear' button.

Markup:

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{startPlaceHolder}}" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dtPopup" is-open="openedStart" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />

     <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openStart($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
     </span>
</p>
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" ng-click="clearSearchData()"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
```

AngularJS Controller:

```
$scope.clearSearchData = function () {
    $scope.filterDate.dtPopup= null;
    $scope.startPlaceHolder = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm-dd-yy", startdate);
}

$scope.startPlaceHolder = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm-dd-yy", startdate);
```

However, when opening the calendar again the button is still focused on the **previously** selected date. I can't seem to get at the correct property to programmatically reset that popup calendar date selected. How do I programmatically change the popup calendar date button value selected?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, it seems like you are using both the datepicker from AngularUI and the one from jQuery UI. `$.datepicker.formatDate` is for the jQuery UI one, is it not?

Answer (score -1):

maybe this could help:

```
 .datepicker('update',date)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I believe it does answer the question.